# How to customize a dialog boxes fonts or styles when customizing stamps using JavaScript in Acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf, fonts, dialog, acrobat

How am I able to customize the font style on the dialog box itself in Adobe Acrobat using JavaScript when creating stamps? I'm able to customize after the stamp has already been placed.  But I want to style the dialog box itself.

I have used code such as:

var f = this.getField("list_box1");
f.fontText = "AMGDT";

This only appears to work after the stamp is place.  The stamping part will update it to the assigned font style.  I want the dialog boxes fields to be set to this AMGDT font style.  When they use a list box or a text field, the selections are symbols.

this is what i saw as a suggestion but this only works once the stamp is placed on the PDF:

```
**for (var i = 0; i < numFields; i++) {
    var fName = getNthFieldName(i);
    var f = getField(fName);
    if (f.type === "text") {
//      f.alignment ="center";
        f.textSize = 6;
        f.textFont = "Helvetica";
        // Other properties go here
    }
}**
```

https://texascreative.com/blog/automated-form-field-styling-goodbye-times-new-roman-hello-acrobat

I want my list box or text fields font to be set to something other than the defaults for the dialog box I use when customizing the stamp to be placed on a PDF using Acrobat.

Comment: Are you asking to customize the fields in the dialog or in the resulting stamp? You have very little control over the dialog display.

Comment: I want to change the font style of my editable list box and text fields in the dialog box.  Is there no way to do this?

Comment: There's no way to do that. You can make some minor changes to the static_text elements but that's it and even those styles are limited.